# security exception connecting spark master java

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I'm new at Spark. In my project, I set master url and app name as SparkConf object.

here is my code

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.bson.BSONObject;
import com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat;
import com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat;

public class SparkExample {

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    conf.set("mongo.job.input.format", "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat");

    conf.set("mongo.input.uri", "mongodb://192.168.1.149:27017/test.sns");



    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://localhost:7077").setAppName("vedat"));

    JavaPairRDD<Object, BSONObject> documents = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, MongoInputFormat.class, Object.class,
            BSONObject.class);

    Configuration outConfig = new Configuration();

    outConfig.set("mongo.job.output.format", "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat");

    outConfig.set("mongo.output.uri", "mongodb://192.168.1.149:27017/test.ou");

    documents.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("file://44", Object.class, BSONObject.class, MongoOutputFormat.class,
            outConfig);

    Configuration bsonConf = new Configuration();
    bsonConf.set("mongo.job.output.format", "com.mongodb.hadoop.BSONFileOutputFormat");

    // documents.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("hds://localhost:8020/user/spark/demo",
    // Object.class, BSONObject.class,
    // BSONFileOutputformat.class, bsonConf);

}
```

}

When I run code I get this stack trace

```
ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.FilterRegistration"'s      signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:952)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:666)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:794)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:136)
at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:129)
at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:98)
at    
org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.createServletHandler(JettyUtils.scala:108)

at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.createServletHandler(JettyUtils.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.attachPage(WebUI.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI$$anonfun$attachTab$1.apply(WebUI.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI$$anonfun$attachTab$1.apply(WebUI.scala:62)
at  scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.attachTab(WebUI.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.initialize(SparkUI.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.<init>(SparkUI.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:190)
at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.createLiveUI(SparkUI.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:440)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
at tr.vedat.spark.SparkExample.main(SparkExample.java:24)
15/07/20 14:44:42 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint:       MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
15/07/20 14:44:42 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error stopping SparkContext after init error.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at      
  org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.close(NettyBlockTransfe   rService.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.stop(BlockManager.scala:1214)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1657)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:565)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
at tr.vedat.spark.SparkExample.main(SparkExample.java:24)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: class    "javax.servlet.FilterRegistration"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:952)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:666)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:794)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:136)
at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:129)
at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:98)
at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.createServletHandler(JettyUtils.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.createServletHandler(JettyUtils.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.attachPage(WebUI.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI$$anonfun$attachTab$1.apply(WebUI.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI$$anonfun$attachTab$1.apply(WebUI.scala:62)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.attachTab(WebUI.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.initialize(SparkUI.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.<init>(SparkUI.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:190)
at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.createLiveUI(SparkUI.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:440)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
at tr.vedat.spark.SparkExample.main(SparkExample.java:24)
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>tr.com.vedat</groupId>
<artifactId>aa</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>aa</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-app</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-hadoop-core_1.0.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-rc0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

So, can anyone help me to show what I'm doing wrong? Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: It has nothing to do with spark itself. You clearly have two (or more) jars with javax.servlet package in it on your classpath. If you're using maven or sth, please show it.

Comment: @szefuf I added my pom.xml. I excluded javax.servlet but still I'm getting same exception. You can see it on pom.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark-core depends on:
org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:3.0.0.v201112011016

You should exclude it. Not sure if it's the only problem, but at least part of it if you run it inside other container.

Comment: I changed pom.xml and problem resolved. Main reason of this exception caused because of javax.servlet version conflict. Thanks.